# Joomla site "Not found" error

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla 2.5 site set up but when I try to access the domain I get an **intermittent** error on the screen just saying "Not found". It sometimes happends when visiting with `www`, sometimes with `http://` and sometimes with `http://www`.

Here is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTGFx.jpg

I have done a thorough look into the domain and all the DNS and records are working as expected and resolving correctly all around the world making me think it must be a Joomla error of some kind. 
I have also tried to enter the sites domain into the $live_url in the configuration file but it stil happends.

Any help or ideas greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's *sometimes* not finding your site, so not knowing if you host the site or you use a service...

We occasionally experience this if we haven't copied the site across all the servers on our load balancer - Perhaps checking if all your servers have the site, or if your host has load balancing and it didn't get propogated properly.  Also be sure the apache or htaccess settings are the same to account for the www or not.

Answer (score 0):

Either you installed Joomla to another directory or the DNS still haven't resolved. Try to ping your site to see which IP it's responding to.